# Crop figures generated by "picture" environment

Tags: crop, croptrim, picture-mode

I've got this piece this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
My equation
\begin{equation*}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
  \fbox{\begin{picture}(17,5)(-1.5,0)
      \thicklines
      \put(3.2,3){$x_5$}
      \put(3.2,1){$x_6$}
      \put(4,3){\line(1,-1){1}}
      \put(4,1){\line(1,1){1}}
      \put(5,2){\circle*{0.15}}
      \put(5,2){\line(1,0){2}}
      \put(5.9,1.5){$x_9$}
      \put(7,2){\circle*{0.15}}
      \put(7,2){\line(1,1){1}}
      \put(7.6,2.2){$x_8$}
      \put(8,3){\line(2,1){1}}
      \put(8,3){\line(2,-1){1}}
      \put(8,3){\circle*{0.15}}
      \put(9.3,3.5){$x_9$}
      \put(9.3,2.3){$x_7$}
      \put(7,2){\line(2,-1){2}}
      \put(9.3,0.9){$x_7$}
  \end{picture}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

That produces this layout (the vertical red line comes from xdvi viewer):
[image]

My question is: how can I crop the figure (remove the extra space around it)?

Comment: you have specified the size `(17,5)` so you can specify a smaller size if you wish.

Comment: I thoght I could save the figure with the standalone class and than crop it... Could it be faster?

Comment: why make it over-sized then crop? that will require multiple file accesses and be much slower

Comment: I'm not the maker of the figure... I'm a typesetter and I'm searching for a solution to manage these cases in a faster way. I could write an Emacs script with some Bash code in it... however, yours answer is right. Perhaps my question is badly asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The size of the picture is specified in the options to the environment, your 17 was making it over sized

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
My equation
\begin{equation*}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
  \fbox{\begin{picture}(7,3.5)(3,0.5)
      \thicklines
      \put(3.2,3){$x_5$}
      \put(3.2,1){$x_6$}
      \put(4,3){\line(1,-1){1}}
      \put(4,1){\line(1,1){1}}
      \put(5,2){\circle*{0.15}}
      \put(5,2){\line(1,0){2}}
      \put(5.9,1.5){$x_9$}
      \put(7,2){\circle*{0.15}}
      \put(7,2){\line(1,1){1}}
      \put(7.6,2.2){$x_8$}
      \put(8,3){\line(2,1){1}}
      \put(8,3){\line(2,-1){1}}
      \put(8,3){\circle*{0.15}}
      \put(9.3,3.5){$x_9$}
      \put(9.3,2.3){$x_7$}
      \put(7,2){\line(2,-1){2}}
      \put(9.3,0.9){$x_7$}
  \end{picture}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```